# How to program a simple music sequencer for Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, audio

**What I want to do:**

I would like to program a very simple music sequencer for Android. But I've never worked with audio on Android or in Java, respectively.

**What the application should do:**

- play back samples (WAVE/OGG files)
- play several audio channels simultaneously (e.g. the trumpet and the flute should play simultaneously, maximum of 10 instruments)
- change the pitch of the samples (e.g. the trumpet WAVE file must be played in normal pitch (c4) and lower/higher pitch (e2/g6) and so on)

This is what the application should be able to do in general.

What components do I need? A normal media player (AudioManager?) won't work, right?

There are already some applications which do what I am thinking about:

- FingerBeat for iOS
- FL Studio Mobile for iOS
- Uloops Studio for Android

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is very simple open source beat sequencer for Android called [SoundFuse](http://androidaalto.org/soundfuse/). They have description and screenshots on the page.

[Here](https://github.com/AndroidAalto/SoundFuse) is the github repository.

Comment: Thank you very much, this project is very interesting and can help me a lot I think :)

Answer (score 2):

You have not one simple requirement, but three very different requirements.

1. Playing WAV should be supported out of the box by the JRE with the help of the classes in javax.sound.sampled, it jsut requires some code to wire it up (not too sure about android).
2. Playing OGG is not supported out of the box. There is an open source implementation for OGG called jOrbis, see their [web site](http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/). Again this can require some wiring code to hook into your application.
3. For a Sequencer, you could just use MIDI. Again it should be supported by the JRE, and if it is not on your platform, you can use Gervill - a pure Java MIDI sequencer ([Project web site](http://java.net/projects/gervill/pages/Home)).
4. There is also a ModPlayer that can play good old Soundtracker and some others. This can also be abused as a Sequencer of some sort if you know the Soundtracker or Screamtracker module format (ancient format, but descriptions are still available on the net). Player with source can be found [here](http://www.quippy.de/mod_en.php). The Tracker formats are not all that ancient by the way, some of todays game engines still make use of them.
5. If you really want, you can cook up your own Sequencer, all the basic stuff if there in javax.sound.sampled. It just requires some basic knowledge about digital sound and a big lot of wiring code.

There is no single solution for *all* your needs, you will have to stitch you own together from the building blocks freely available.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed survey. But according to Boude's link (http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) Android supports OGG natively.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with details on Android, just summarized what I knew is available/needed on a standard JRE.

Answer (score 2):

I won't be able to provide a complete answer, but I will point you in the right direction.

Android does support .wav and .ogg decoding. According to: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I don't have any experience in audio, but your best bet seems to be the SoundPool class, it allows you to adjust pitch and volume and it seems to be able to play multiple sounds simultaneously: "Note that calling play() may cause another sound to stop playing if the maximum number of active streams is exceeded."
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

There also is a MediaPlayer class, but this is for more simple use. I don't think it allows pitch control.

Comment: Thank you very much, Boude, you finally convinced me to use the SoundPool class :)

Answer (score 2):

I made something similar for my application (playing trombones sample). After a lot of experiencing, I found the best solution was to use AudioTrack.
Have a look at my source code: 
http://code.google.com/p/trombonino/source/browse/trunk/src/com/trombonino

Especially

http://code.google.com/p/trombonino/source/browse/trunk/src/com/trombonino/Trombone.java
http://code.google.com/p/trombonino/source/browse/trunk/src/com/trombonino/WavFile.java

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at your code and I'm sure it can help me. Could you explain why you didn't use SoundPool? To me this class seems to be the most fitting one.

Comment: My first versions used soundpool. But looping with soundpool produce an annoying "click" between each loop (at least on my desire and reported by some users) which wasn't acceptable for music samples.

Comment: Also, with audiotrack, you can loop within the sound file instead of looping the whole file (better for samples). As far as I can remember, I also quickly ran into memory problems with soundpool, also with few smalls samples.

Answer (score 1):

You will have problems with your timing on the Android system. To avoid your sequencer thread being interrupted by garbage collection you probably need to write the sequencer in native using the ndk.

Playing back the sounds is probably best to do using the ndk as well.

Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/high-performance-audio/

In the above Soundfuse example the sequencer uses SystemClock.sleep() that is never a good idea. Check [Why using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() is a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995938/why-using-system-threading-thread-sleep-is-a-bad-practice).

Realized this question is really old but will answer it anyway since no answer mentions the NDK.