# Why using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() is a bad practice?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

I'm writing an application working with a big and ugly 3rd party system via a complicated API.
Sometimes some errors happen in the system, but if we wait for my program to face this errors it can be too late.

So, I use a separate thread to check the system state as following:

```
while (true)
{
    ask_state();
    check_state();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

It doesn't really matter if I check the system state once in 100 ms or once a minute.

But I have heard that using Thread.Sleep() is a bad practice. Why? And what can I do in this situation?

Comment: If you want to check something periodically, why not use a timer?

Comment: The main question is 'is the timer better or not? and why Thread.Sleep() is bad?'

Comment: Because you keep a thread alive unnecessary. The question whether this really matters is of course depending on your context. If you have a simple application then using a periodic timer or a dedicated thread would most likely not generate any performance differences since the timer will simply force a thread from the thread pool to stay alive.

Comment: In general though (and in particular with a heavily multi-threaded application), there are more descriptive alternatives. e.g. a timer.

Comment: 'I have heard that using Thread.Sleep() is a bad practice' - almost anything can be misused.  Does your code above work?  If so, just leave it.

Comment: @MartinJames of course, it does =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason is that `Thread.Sleep()` is blocking your code from doing anything else. Recent efforts is to make blocking as least as possible. For example, node.js is a non-blocking language.

**Update: I don't know about the infrastructure of `Timer` class in C#. Maybe it's also blocking.**

You can schedule a task to check that third API every 100 ms. This way, during that 100 ms, your program can do other tasks.

**Update:** This analogy might help. If we compare operating system to a hospital, and compare the threads to nurses in that hospital, the supervisor (programmer) can choose a policy:

1. Either to ask each nurse (thread) to watch one, and only one patient (a job, a task to be done), even if between each check she waits for an hour (`Sleep()` method)
2. To ask each nurse to check each patient, and during the interval till next check, go on and check other patients.

The first model is blocking. It's not scalable. But in the second model, even with few nurses, you might be able to serve many patients.

Comment: Separate thread doesn't mean that it's non-blocking. During that time, the other thread would be put on hold and won't go back to thread-pool in order to do the job.

Comment: "the other thread would be put on hold and won't go back to thread-pool in order to do the job" - can you explain in detail how it can be? The check thread nor ask_state nor check_state() don't have any locks

Comment: @Polity, thread are like workers. Even if it's not a thread from thread-pool, it's an OS resource that is being used. And this resource  should wait 100 ms to check again.

Comment: @user2862319, to understand threads, I recommend that you think of each thread as a nurse in a hospital (OS). What happens if each nurse only check one patient, and wait for one hour between each check? How many patients that hospital can receipt?

Comment: I'm simply pointing out that your statement: 'blocking your code from doing anything else' is misleading. Besides, one have to remember that with simple applications, a timer can force the threadpool to maintain more threads active than actually would have been the case when using a dedicated thread. No judgement to use a dedicated thread for sure.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: Do you believe that timers don't `Sleep` (in one way or another) until they need to fire their elapsed event?  Of course the timer is operating on another thread, abstraction doesn't change that.  Simple wait loops are perfectly fine for many tasks.

Comment: @EdS. Timers (depending on the implementation) are managed and invoked by the OS so they might 'sleep' although they are not as selfish as say Thread.Sleep to occupy a thread while they do so

Comment: @EdS., yeah, you're right. Timers might also sleep under the hood. I just wanted to point out that `blocking` model is considered a bad practice, and using `Sleep` is a way to overuse blocking approach.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati so, you want to say that a thread uses some system resources while timer uses less of these resources, am I right?

Comment: No @user2862319, I'm not trying to say that :D. I just want to say that one reason they discourage using `Sleep` is that it's blocking. I don't know about the infrastructure of `Timer`. Maybe that also uses `Sleep` under the hood.

Comment: OTOH, using timers means writing code as a quite-possibly-messy asynchronous state-machine instead of inline as with seperate threads, where Sleep() can be called anywhere at any function depth.  Firing a timer from a timer-management thread requires at least as many context-changes as a Sleep() call, and maybe double if the timer callback signals another thread that is waiting on input messages.

Comment: Yeah @MartinJames, sometimes it's faster to just do the job, rather than figuring out what to do first and what to do next. But in general, keeping far from `Sleep` is a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Because the only way to shut down this thread if it's waiting inside the [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is to either a) wait for the `Sleep` to end, or b) use one of [`Thread.Abort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Thread.Interrupt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).<sup>1</sup>

If it's a long sleep, then (a) isn't really suitable if you're trying to be responsive. And (b) are pretty obnoxious if the code *happens* to **not** actually be inside the `Sleep` at the time.

It's far better, if you want to be able to interrupt the sleeping behaviour in a suitable fashion, to use a waitable object (such as e.g. a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) - you might then even be able to place the wait on the waitable object into the `while` conditional, to make it clear what will cause the thread to exit.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've use shutdown in this instance because it's a very common scenario where cross-thread communication is required. But for any other cross-thread signalling or communication, the same arguments can also apply, and if it's *not* shutdown then `Thread.Abort` or `Thread.Interrupt` are even less suitable.

Comment: Well, while what you say in the first paragraph is true, it often does not matter, eg. if the thread is expected to run for the entire lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

i would set a timer to whatever ms you want and wait for my check methods to complete, by the way do you want to use an eternal loop or it is not a complete code that you showed up there ?
ok this is a sample of what i'm talking about:

```
public void myFunction()
{
int startCount = Environment.TickCount;
ask_state();
check_state();

while (true)
{
if (Environment.TickCount - startCount >= 20000) //two seconds 
{
break;
}
Application.DoEvents();
}
}

//Now you have an organized function that makes the task you want just call it every
// time interval, again you can use a timer to do that for you

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            myFunction();
}
```

good luck

Comment: If everything is OK, my program should run. And if it's running, it should check the system state. It will be changed to while (running) in future releases

Comment: ok so just use a timer instead of sleep(), here is a sample of what im talking about :